# Add Sprite at collision location - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to do is add a medium asteroid at the location of the large asteroid after the large asteroid has collided with a laser beam.

My issue is that the medium asteroid is always added to the bottom left corner of the screen and regardless of where the large asteroid was at the time of the collision.

Below is all the relevant code from my program.

```
- (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryLaserbeam | CNPhysicsCategoryAsteroidLarge))
    {
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"laserbeam"
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
         {
             [node removeFromParent];
             *stop = YES;
             NSLog(@"laser explode");
         }];

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"large_asteroid"
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
         {
             CGPoint oldPosition = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y);
             NSLog(@"oldPosition x: %f, y: %f", oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y);
             [node removeFromParent];
             [self addMediumAsteroid:oldPosition];
             *stop = YES;
             NSLog(@"large explode");
         }];


    }
}


- (void) addMediumAsteroid:(CGPoint)position
{
    _asteroidMedium.position = position;
    NSLog(@"postion x: %f, y: %f", position.x, position.y);
    [self addChild:_asteroidMedium];
    NSLog(@"add medium");
}
```

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"oldPosition x: %f, y: %f", oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y);` output?

Comment: the position of the large asteroid

Comment: Obviously, I'm saying the actually values. If it was the position, `_asteroidMedium.position = position;` would work.

Comment: Do you create a medium asteroid? I don't see you creating one in the addMediumAsteroid: method.

Comment: John - the actual values are never the same
Mad pig - yes, the third line in the addMediumAsteroid: method
          [self addChild:_asteroidMedium];

Comment: I guess I'm confused. [self addChild:_asteroidMedium] looks like it's using a pointer "_asteroidMedium" to addChild. Seems like you are just adding the same object and not creating any new objects.

Comment: If you do an NSLog(@" object: %@", _asteroidMedium);, do you actually get a different object each time addMediumAsteroid: is called?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the large asteroids to the same "self"?

Comment: Did you add any type of camera such as worldNode, as the child of self. if so that would be your problem